# Infer NODE_MODULE_VERSION from a binary node module

Tags: node.js, module, version

Given a binary node module, how do I infer a NODE_MODULE_VERSION it is built with?

Comment: the package.json is always unpacked when a module is installed

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I'm not installing a module, I have a module binary file and I want to identify, which version of node it is built with.